# simple javascript decimal addition produces incorrect results

Tags: javascript, math

I have the following function:

```
var a = 0.1;
var b = 0.2;

function checkValue(){
    if(a + b === 0.3){
        alert('statement is true');   
    }
    else {
        alert('statement is false');   
    }
}

checkValue();
```

This function evaluates to false??
[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bMaBF/)

Now, the same function with different decimals that also equal 0.3:

```
var a = 0.15;
var b = 0.15;

function checkValue(){
    if(a + b === 0.3){
        alert('statement is true');   
    }
    else {
        alert('statement is false');   
    }
}

checkValue();
```

evaluates to true.

Has anyone run into this before? If so are there languages commonly used for web applications that do not do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the floating point problem by fixing the decimal like this:

```
if((a + b).toFixed(1) == 0.3){
 alert('statement is true');   
}else{
 alert('statement is false');   
}
```

Comment: Yep that works. I will try it on larger floating points to test limits.

Comment: There is no problem and this is not a fix. That the binary (truncated) floating point numbers represent different and sometimes unintuitive intervals than the decimal truncated numbers is expected and well-known. To use rounding to extract the valid decimal places is the recommended procedure. You need not be timid, toFixed(10) would work as well for numbers smaller than 1e5.

Answer (score 1):

Floating numbers are inaccurate in JS. It's luck that the second example evaluates to true for you... it may not on someone else's computer. For workarounds, see this thread:
[How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

Comment: The odd thing is that the second example consistently evaluates to true and the first consistently evaluates to false. I just tried in 3 different browser consoles on 3 different machines. I get that js doesn't parse decimals perfectly, but if it is just luck why do the two functions produce persist in producing the same results?

Comment: Open your javascript console to see part of the reason why... run `console.log(0.1 + 0.2)` and `console.log(0.15 + 0.15)`. The second one probably has 20 digits before a non-zero or something, and it's getting chopped off so it happens to evaluate to 0.3. The point is, Javascript floating numbers are unreliable for direct comparisons like that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. the first example evaluates to 0.30000000000000004 thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: @HamzaKubba, it is not JavaScript math that is "unreliable" or "broken", it is the general [binary floating point arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). JavaScript is is doing nothing special, just using 64bit double numbers the way the FPU handles them. It is only showing a more that complete representation of the internal binary representation where other languages/compilers apply more sensible rounding or rounding to much less accuracy by default.

Comment: Never said they were unreliable or broken, just that they are "unreliable for direct comparisons like that". That's a good description of how they work though.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are inaccurate in most programming languages due to the way that they store values.

So, `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` evaluates to `false` and **only** `0.3` will ever `== 0.3`.

It's actually interesting how many large-scale issues this has caused in deployed software and major companies.

Comment: I thought it was an interesting issue too.

Comment: `3/10 == 0.3; // true`

Comment: Any company losing money on this richly deserves to (do you have a link to a true story or is this just an urban myth?). This is known and expected behavior since the invention of binary floating point formats, not some kind of Pentium bug.

Comment: @LutzL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug

Comment: Yes, that's the Pentium bug. But the general and unavoidable peculiarities of floating point formats in binary representations, which are in question here, are in an absolutely different category.

Comment: @cookie monster - It is true but why? I am new to js and programming in general and I am trying to understand. It seems like 3/10 should = Infinity logically.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bMaBF/4/).

its working.

use this code in javascript

```
variable.toFixed(2)
```

Comment: If you amend the alert string to `alert('statement is true:\n  '+a.toFixed(25)+"\n+"+b.toFixed(25)+"\n="+(a+b).toFixed(25));` then you see what exactly happens internally. A much greater curiousity is that by this rounding arithmetic, `0555+1110=4440`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

a + b = 0.300004
So you will have to use .toFixed()

```
var a = 0.1;
var b = 0.2;

function checkValue(){
    var answer = a + b;
    alert(answer.toFixed(1))
if(answer === 0.3){
 alert('statement is true');   
}
else {
 alert('statement is false');   
}
}

checkValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add those together, for some odd reason it returns as `30000000000000004`. To fix this, as listed above, you can use the `.toFixed(1)`, which rounds to a certain decimal place, based on the argument number you give it. There are other ways to round as well. You can do `Math.round()`, but beware as this cuts of ANY decimal places. Hope this helps a bit.